# Phantom drive net use

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I ran `net use` on the P: drive then later switched back to drive C: and issued `net use p: /d`.

Now the P: drive letter is no longer available to the `net use` command. When I try to issue another `net use`  command I receive:

> System error 85 has occurred.
>   The local device name is already in use

When I type `p:` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I receive: `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password`

When I type `net use p: /d` again, I receive: `The network connection could not be found`

How can I clear this phantom drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there's nothing weird about `net use` and Windows7.

I had another (custom) application that was using `net use` in the background and it still had the drive mapped.  Why I was getting the Logon Failure message, though, just by typing `p:` <kbd>Enter</kbd> is beyond me.

After finding and uninstalling that app, problem solved.